# Script doesn't recognized file extension to upload pdf in php

Tags: php

I try to modify the php scrip to allow it to upload pdf instead of image. I've done several modification but none of them are working. I really appreciate if someone can show me how to modify this script to allow uploading the pdf.
I'm very new in php and need more guidance from php experts out there.
Thanks in advance for your kind assistance.

Anyway this is the code:

```
## Heading ##<html>
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">      

<style>
#uploader {
  width: 300px; 
  height: 200px; 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.075) url(../../img/pdf_icon.png) repeat fixed left;
  border-radius:8px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  }
  #uploader.highlight {
    background:#ff0;
  }
  #uploader.disabled {
    background:#aaa;
  }
  </style>

  <script src="drag-drop-upload-pdf.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- DROP ZONE -->
  <div id="uploader">
  Muatnaik fail pdf di sini...
  </div>

  <!-- STATUS -->
  <div id="upstat"></div>

  <!-- FALLBACK -->
  <form action="upload-pdf.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br />
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" accept="pdf/*">
    <br />
    <br />
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>


## PHP Script ##
<?php
// SOURCE + DESTINATION
$source = $_FILES["file-upload"]["tmp_name"];
$destination = __DIR__.'/../../download/'. $_FILES["file-upload"]["name"];
echo "Uploaded ";
$error = "";

// CHECK IF FILE ALREADY EXIST
if (file_exists($destination)) {
$error = $destination . " already exist.";
}

// ALLOWED FILE EXTENSIONS
if ($error == "") {
$allowed = ["application/pdf", "application/x-pdf", "application/acrobat", "applications/vnd.pdf", 
"text/pdf". "text/x-pdf"];
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["file-upload"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
$error = "$ext file type not allowed. File must be uploaded in PDF format. - " . $_FILES["file- 
upload"]["name"];
  }
}

// LEGIT TEXT FILE CHECK
if ($error == "") {
if (getimagesize($_FILES["file-upload"]["tmp_name"]) == false) {
$error = $_FILES["file-upload"]["name"] . " is not a valid file.";
  }
}

// FILE SIZE CHECK
if ($error == "") {
// 1,000,000 = 1MB
if ($_FILES["file-upload"]["size"] > 50000000) {
$error = $_FILES["file-upload"]["name"] . " - file size too big!";
  }
}

// ALL CHECKS OK - MOVE FILE
if ($error == "") {
if (!move_uploaded_file($source, $destination)) {
$error = "Error moving $source to $destination";
  }
}

// ERROR OCCURED OR OK?
if ($error == "") {
echo $_FILES["file-upload"]["name"] . " Upload DONE.";
} else {
echo $error;
}
?>
```

Comment: `$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["file-upload"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));` is your culprit. Specifically, its not going ever return one of your array values in `$allowed`. Edit: So `$allowed` is actually your culprit. `$ext` as you have it defined will return the dot extension of the file.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. It is better to show us what did you try, not just mention.

Answer (score 0):

Try change this in HTML:

**accept="application/pdf"**

Comment: I've changed it but it still doesn't work... <input class="btn btn-primary" type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" accept="application/pdf">